# Reading MIDI Files

Tags: java, midi

What is the best way to read a MIDI file (chronologically) with multiple tracks? (Java)

Note: I don't want to play the MIDI file, just read the messages.

Couple ideas:

Is it safe to assume there are no note events shorter than the 1/64th note? Or should I visit every track and only move to the next tick after all other ticks tracks

- Assume there is no midi event shorter than a 1/64th note, and move the current position tick count by that fix delta.
- Visit every track and progress to the next earliest tick

Comment: It's not safe to assume 1/64th notes, 1/128 also exist for example. However, it is safe to assume that the data is stored in a single byte. (You can assess those with the MidiMessage class).

Comment: @yxk I also like create proper sheet music from Midi file. Have you and guide for me to start up ?

Comment: Anvil Studio has a $60 option that will print sheet music from midi files.
Also, anyone know any open source java options reading a MIDI file?

Answer (score 3):

[JFugue](http://www.JFugue.org) can read a MIDI file and sort the messages in chronological order.

The results can be read as JFugue MusicStrings (for example, C-sharp, 5th octave, whole note = "C#5w"), or you can write your own ParserListener and attach it to the MidiParser so you can output your own text.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can read a midi file with :

```
try {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.setSequence(MidiSystem.getSequence(yourMidiFile));
        sequencer.open();
        sequencer.start();
        while(true) {
            if(sequencer.isRunning()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Check every second
                } catch(InterruptedException ignore) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

} catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
} finally {
    // Close resources
    sequencer.stop();
    sequencer.close();
}
```

This code should read your midi files (even if there are multiple tracks)

Comment: I don't necessarily want to play the sequence, just get the event messages in the tracks

Comment: @srand I'm assuming this is just an example, you can use the MidiSystem, Sequence and Track classes to read out the MidiEvents stored in the file.

Comment: @Jasper Yeah, that's what I'm doing currently, however its a serial/sequential read of the midi file (and not chronological).