# Read Midi Messages from a Midi File in Java

Tags: java, midi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading MIDI files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850688/reading-midi-files-in-java)

I have a midi file, and I'm trying to read the file and basically dump all the messages from the midi file into a text file.

so far I'm reading in my file and storing it in a Sequence (javax.sound.midi.Sequence) Object.
However when I try and read the messages from the track events I get memory locations.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought my question wasn't answered on here before, but it seems the solution was there.

[Reading MIDI files in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850688/reading-midi-files-in-java)

Apologies.