# Output midi file to console while being played in Java

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I am trying to read a midi file and output when the note is played, the note, and velocity. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850688/reading-midi-files-in-java) would work great but it doesn't output the data live when the note is played. The code that plays the midi:

```
package midistep;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;

public class MidiReadAndPlay {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Sequencer sequencer;
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("midifile.mid")));
        sequencer.setSequence(is);
        sequencer.start();
    }
}
```

The code from the question I mention earlier doesn't output the data live. It just outputs it all at once. I would like it to output the sequencer data when the note is played so then it could be used later.

Comment: I am afraid you need to create two threads, or rewrite the logic of `Sequencer`.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to connect your own `Receiver` to the sequencer's `Transmitter`.

Comment: @CL. How would I be able to do that? Do you have a link to some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to outputting the note note data in time was to add a receiver with custom code:

```
public class MidiReadAndPlay {

    public static Receiver synthRcvr = new CustomReceiver();
    public static Transmitter seqTrans;
    public static Synthesizer synth;
    public static Sequencer sequencer;
    public static Sequence sequence;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {      
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File("midi.mid"));

        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        seqTrans = sequencer.getTransmitter();
        seqTrans.setReceiver(synthRcvr);

        sequencer.open(); 
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

        sequencer.start();
    }

}
```

Receiver:

```
public class CustomReceiver implements Receiver {

    public CustomReceiver() {

    }
    public static final int NOTE_ON = 0x90;
    public static final int NOTE_OFF = 0x80;
    public static final String[] NOTE_NAMES = {"C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"};

    @Override
    public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp) {
        if (message instanceof ShortMessage) {
            ShortMessage sm = (ShortMessage) message;
            System.out.print("Channel: " + sm.getChannel() + " ");
            if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_ON) {
                int key = sm.getData1();
                int octave = (key / 12)-1;
                int note = key % 12;
                String noteName = NOTE_NAMES[note];
                int velocity = sm.getData2();
                System.out.println("Note on, " + noteName + octave + " key=" + key + " velocity: " + velocity);
            } else if (sm.getCommand() == NOTE_OFF) {
                int key = sm.getData1();
                int octave = (key / 12)-1;
                int note = key % 12;
                String noteName = NOTE_NAMES[note];
                int velocity = sm.getData2();
                System.out.println("Note off, " + noteName + octave + " key=" + key + " velocity: " + velocity);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Command:" + sm.getCommand());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Other message: " + message.getClass());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```